# get user_id, rating from webscraping pictures

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a dataframe from web scraping all pages from the website [animeka](http://www.animeka.com/animes/series/~_1.html) website:

```
import pandas as pd 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for page_no in range(1, 467):
    url = 'http://www.animeka.com/animes/~_{}.html'.format(page_no)

    titles, studios, genres, durations = [], [], [], []

for page_no in range(1, 467):
    url = 'http://www.animeka.com/animes/~_{}.html'.format(page_no)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    for table in soup.find_all('table', class_='animesindex'):
        td = table.find_all('td', class_='animestxt')
        titles.append(td[1].text.split(':')[1])
        studios.append(td[3].text.split(':')[1])
        genres.append(td[4].text.split(':')[1])
        durations.append(td[6].text.split(':')[1])

headers = ['Title', 'Studio', 'Genres', 'Duration']
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(headers, [titles, studios, genres, durations])))
df = pd.DataFrame({'duration':df["Duration"], "genre" : df["Genres"], 'studio':df["Studio"], "titre" : df["Title"]})
```

And I would like to get user_id and rating they put for each anime but this is in picture in "detail" subsection and I do not know how to do to gather that information.

This is a picture code where rating is:

```
<img src="/animes/13498.png" width="400" height="100" alt="graph">
```

[image: image containing a rating]

Comment: So, is your question - How to extract information from images?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find_previous` method to find tags and strings that come before a particular tag in the document.

```
td[1].find_previous('td')
```

So, if you wanted to extract the name of the image, you'd try this:

```
td[1].find_previous('td').img['src'].split('/')[-1]
```